# Display Result of MYSQL Count

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm using a query to output a list of members of a shoutbox and their shout count:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS Shouts
FROM shouts
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY Shouts DESC
```

Which displays:

User1: 3490
User2: 1234
User3: 345
...

I've tried the following:

```
$result = mysql_query(the query above);
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $count['Shouts'];
```

but it only displays the first row. How can I display the whole result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the mysql_fetch_array within a loop:

```
while ($count = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $count['Shouts'];
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I did try that before, but I must've wrote it wrong as it was displaying hundreds of rows and eventually crashed FF. Thanks!